# printing list of lists in python with space delimited text

Tags: python, linux, list, delimiter

I have:

```
surfaceList = [(21, 22, 2, 4, 24), (27, 28, 7, 4, 30)]
```

I want:

```
The vertex are 21 22 2 4 24
The vertex are 27 28 7 4 30
```

I used

```
totalSurface = len(surfaceList)
print " total surface = %d " % (totalSurface)
for surfaceGenNew  in range(totalSurface):
 print " The vertex are  " surfaceList[surfaceGenNew]
```

Error is:

```
print "  The vertex are %s" surfaceInformationVertexList[surfaceGenNew]
^
Error: invalid syntax
```

I also used

```
foo = [(21, 22, 2, 4, 24), (27, 28, 7, 4, 30)]
print " \n The vertex are ".join(foo)
```

Error is

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

I could use the hard way of finding the length of individual list and then use the if condition for each list item and then print the same, but I am sure there would be smart way to do it.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of tuples. Try

```
for s in surfaceList:
    print("The vertex are {0}".format(" ".join(str(x) for x in s)))
```

1. The `for` loop allows you to print every tuple in its own line (there are other ways but I find this one more readable than others).
2. The `.join` together with the comprehension (to convert `int` values inside the tuples to `str`) formats your tuple such that every value is separated by a space. The `{0}` inside the format string is a placeholde that designates it will be replaced by the first (index 0) argument of the `.format()` call.
3. The `.format()` concatenates the text (The vertex are...) and the space separated values.

Comment: gives an error  :  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: It works fine, can you please explain two things?  1: how the delimitation works in this case and how {0} works, it would help me to use it in future by myself..  2: how did you get +3 so quickly :) as I got a -1 so quickly!

Comment: @HamadHassan Sure, just added extra info about the methods used. Not exactly sure why you got downvoted as this is a valid and on-topic question.

Comment: I am thankful for your time and explanation since it is a one liner and I am beginner, I broke it down. Can you please tell me where I got it wrong ?                                                                                          for s in surfaceList:
 for x in s:
  print("The vertex are {0}".format(" ".join((str(x)))))

Comment: By the time you are in the nested for loop you are already getting individual element from tuple and join() can be done only on a sequence of strings.  Try this:

for s in surfaceList:
    print_string = "The vertex are " 

    for x in s:
        print_string += str(x) + " "
    
    print print_string[:-1]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed things in the way you wrote:

```
surfaceList = [(21, 22, 2, 4, 24), (27, 28, 7, 4, 30)]
totalSurface = len(surfaceList)

print " total surface = %d " % (totalSurface)

for surfaceGenNew  in range(totalSurface):
    print " The vertex are  " + str(surfaceList[surfaceGenNew])[1:-1].replace(",","")
```

but I strongly suggest to go with @selcuk's answer